# Native image using GraalVM, Maven, GluonFX plugin - problem with resource bundle com.sun.glass.ui.win

Tags: maven, javafx, native, gluonfx

GraalVM version: 21.2.0
JavaFX version: 17.0.0.1
Maven version: 3.6.3

I'm very close to be able to run my native image, I added classes to my reflectionlist in the pom.xml etc. but now I'm grinding to a halt because of a resourcebundle not found error. If anyone could give me a hint, that would be much appreciated.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyProject-fxml.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.MyProject.Main</mainClass>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>com.MyProject.MyProject</list>
                        <list>com.MyProject.controllers.MainViewController</list>
                        <list>com.MyProject.controllers.stagecontrollers.SimpleStageController</list>
                        <list>com.MyProject.model.helpers.AppPreferences</list>
                        <list>com.MyProject.model.helpers.ScreenResolution</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.SplitPane</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                    <resourcesList>com.sun.glass.ui.win</resourcesList>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.MyProject.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- TODO: Figure out how to make an executable jar with Maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix></classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.MyProject.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-java</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.MyProject.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Followed by the error output:

```
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Oct 09, 2021 11:19:12 AM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @2715644a'
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Exception in Application start method
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Oct 09, 2021 11:19:12 AM com.MyProject.APP show
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] SEVERE: There is an error launching the JavaFX runtime, or the application class cannot be constructed (e.g., if the class is not public or is not in an exported package), or an Exception or Error is thrown by the Application constructor, init method, start method, or stop method.java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:567)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsJavaThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsJavaThreads.java:138)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:315)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:548)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:260)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1020)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:757)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.MyProject.MyProject.loadMainViewParent(APP.java:88)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.MyProject.MyProject.start(APP.java:55)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:105)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     ... 3 more
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com/sun/glass/ui/win/themes, locale en_US
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1593)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1556)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:857)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.getHighContrastScheme(WinApplication.java:344)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.getHighContrastTheme(WinApplication.java:350)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.getThemeName(QuantumToolkit.java:1809)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl._setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:924)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:723)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:687)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:99)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]     ... 23 more
[Sat Oct 09 11:19:12 CEST 2021][SEVERE] Process run until end failed with result: 1
```

So, the resource "com/sun/glass/ui/win/themes" is missing. I can't find however how to correct for this one.

Comment: See https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_bundleslist with the default bundles added. If you need a new one you can use `<bundlesList/>`. (This should be fixed in the next plugin release).

Comment: Ah ok, great to know! I'll try tomorrow again, I did already try for specifically this bundle and adding that also didn't seem to work, as win/themes is not an existing resource that IntelliJ seems to be able to find.

Comment: Just as a follow-up, it did work to add that bundle, even though IntelliJ didn't have an entrance in the autocompletion for it. Need to research that (probably lack of knowledge here). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jose Pereda, adding the above bundle to `<bundleslist/>` to the `gluonfx-maven-plugin` worked, even though IntelliJ didn't show this path as having a bundle with that name.