# JavaFX Windows Native Image HelloFX example fails: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinView.notifyResize(II)V

Tags: windows, javafx, gluon, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I tried to build and start Gluons HelloFX example as native image for Windows.
Building was successful but starting the resulting executable fails with this exception:

```
==================== RUN TASK ====================
[SUB] Nov 01, 2021 10:33:41 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
[SUB] WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @60723d6a'
[SUB] Exception in Application start method
[SUB] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
[SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
[SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
[SUB]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:552)
[SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsJavaThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsJavaThreads.java:138)
[SUB] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinView.notifyResize(II)V
[SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.jni.functions.JNIFunctions$Support.getMethodID(JNIFunctions.java:1104)
[SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.jni.functions.JNIFunctions$Support.getMethodID(JNIFunctions.java:1089)
[SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.jni.functions.JNIFunctions.GetMethodID(JNIFunctions.java:410)
[SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinView._initIDs(WinView.java)
[SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinView.<clinit>(WinView.java:43)
[SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
[SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
[SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.createView(WinApplication.java:237)
[SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewScene.<init>(ViewScene.java:54)
[SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.createTKScene(WindowStage.java:263)
[SUB]     at javafx.scene.Scene.initPeer(Scene.java:817)
[SUB]     at javafx.scene.Scene$2.initPeer(Scene.java:406)
[SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.initPeer(SceneHelper.java:74)
[SUB]     at javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1112)
[SUB]     at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
[SUB]     at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
[SUB]     at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1190)
[SUB]     at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1205)
[SUB]     at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
[SUB]     at hellofx.HelloFX.start(HelloFX.java:55)
[SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
[SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
[SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
[SUB]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:105)
[SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
[SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
[SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
[SUB]     ... 3 more
```

That was not the first exception I got. Before that I got:
`Can't find bundle for base name com/sun/glass/ui/win/themes, locale en_US`
I fixed that with answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69505447).

I rigorously followed the instructions on the [Gluon documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_windows).

The things I've done:

- downloaded Gluons GraalVM version and extracted it
- set the GRAALVM_HOME
- downloaded VisualStudio 2019 CE and installed it with the required components
- executed `vcvars64.bat`
- cloned latest [gluon-samples](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/)
- `cd HelloFX`
- mvn clean gluonfx:compile
- mvn gluonfx:link

That all worked.
But the last step - running the application - failed: `mvn gluonfx:nativerun`

What I did so far:

- updated the `gluonfx.maven.plugin.version` from `1.0.7` to `1.0.8`
- used GraalVM CE 21.3.0 and added `native-image-installable-svm-java11-windows-amd64-21.3.0.jar` - and got the same error
- added `<bundlesList>com.sun.glass.ui.win.themes</bundlesList>` to the gluonfx-maven-plugin configuration

The OS is Windows 10 Pro 64Bit.

Comment: Find the related issue and fix here: https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin/issues/380

Comment: Thanks. Additionally adding `<jniList><list>com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinView</list></jniList>` to the gluonfx-maven-plugin solved it.

Comment: Try the plugin snapshot, you won’t need any modifications.